# How to transport troops from surface to orbit?

Tags: science-fiction, transportation, vehicles

how could one transport people planetside into orbit when the planet the people are on has no infrastructure for launching stuff into orbit? (this includes rockets and railgunning things into orbit) I would really like to implement this into a story and I'm curious if there's even a glimmer of hope that I can do it without absolute handwavium.

the people being transported would be all types of people.

this should be a very quick affair, a pickup should arrive within a day.

any science fiction solutions allowed, just no magic.

Comment: Have you considered a skycrane ?

Comment: What is the tech level?

Comment: Would it be possible for a shuttle of some kind to land on a body of water? This might simplify the infra-structure needed.

Comment: @FlaStorm32 not entirely possible, some waterless planets have colonies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an upper limit on how fast you can do this, but yes, with minimal handwavium, you might be able to do it.

**How do we do it?**

If you're allowing science fiction, let's handwave a *nuclear fusion turbojet* that allows for extremely efficient propulsion in and out of an atmosphere. You have virtually unlimited $I_{sp}$ and therefore fuel is no longer a concern. Then, you can include whatever landing gear you want so you can touch down just about anywhere. This isn't entirely based in sci-fi either: assuming you have compact nuclear fusion (which is bound to  happen one of these days anyway), you just sit your fusion reactor next to a combination inert gas inlet/air intake and let physics do the work of propulsion. Out of atmosphere, you use the inert gas as propellant, and inside an atmosphere, you use air. Done!

**Is that really realistic?**

If we're talking about Earth, then we're considering a time at which there is a necessity to transport a volume of soldiers from the Earth's surface to orbit in under a day. That is certainly no time soon given the current laws regarding outer space, and so it's honestly not *as* implausible that we have our unobtainium engine figured out by then.

**But how long does it take?**

There is a minimum time that it takes to pick someone up. This is related to orbital velocity. Say you want to pick someone up from Earth's surface and bring them to the ISS. You can wait ~45 minutes (on average, given a 90-minute orbit) for the ISS to be in the right spot, then burn at 1 *g* all the way down till your orbital velocity is zero, at which point you'll be on the surface. Then, you burn back up at 1 *g* straight to the ISS where you deliver your troops to their vacation home (or warzone, or wherever). The ISS is moving at 7.66 kilometers per second, so you're going to need to accelerate twice that much (once going down, once going up) in order to complete the mission. Under ideal conditions, this will take around 26 minutes - more realistically, probably about 30. So, ostensibly, you could deliver troops to low Earth orbit in about 1:15:00.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming troops in orbit can survive and be useful you are talking about a rather high tech, well above what we have now. Are you sure you want them in orbit, not to get them to some other world? It would be helpful to (very generally) describe what kind of troops are they and what you want to do with them.

The obvious approach is to mostly avoid the tech side. There are just ordinary boring space ships delivering cargo to/from planet or refueling, you repurpose them to move troops. You send a representative to a nearby system to rent a few transports. You negotiate a deal with space trade guild/corporation. Advanced aliens suggest to help you for a price. You ask an enemy of your enemy to get assistance. Stuff like that.

If space ships can't enter the atmosphere they should use shuttles of some sort. Normally shuttles would be land based or parked in space station but, if you don't want the planet to have these capabilities they can come with the transport ships.

Shuttle can be rocket based. Or a space plane which climbs up as a plane and then uses space engines. Power source - chemical, fusion or fission reactor. Or some future tech like antimatter, anti gravitational engine, ion drive, beryllium sphere.

In general tech details are not particularly important for a story. It is a technobabble functionally equivalent to magic. It can be fun in small quantities, but focusing on it doesn't make much sense.

Heroes don't have to necessarily understand the tech. "WTF is that? - Oh, It's arkelian trader, you never seen one? - No. Not landing anyway. Awesome. How do they do it? - Trillion credits question. Damn aliens." and proceed to description of landing of an impressive landing of a miracle spaceship.

Comment: absolutely sure I want them in orbit. warships with handwavium warp drives will receive them and teleport them elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

One proposal for more efficient space ship launching is to use magnetic acceleration. Basically you build a curved track, put a specially designed maglev wagon on it which carries the payload you want to go into space (people in this case), then accelerate it along the track. At the end of the track it just releases and flies into space with minimal rocketry necessary just to steer after getting there.

Biggest problem is you kinda need to build it into a mountain as these tracks need to be long, have a shallow curve and preferably be as high as possible.

Other than that, the power necessary compared to the rocketfuel isn’t that big.